# MongoDB average within a nested collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to calculate the average score of a test result across many tests, however the document is nested two levels within the person object.

I cannot get the average within the nested collection

```
{ "name" : "Person Name",
"tests" : [ 
    {
        "testID" : "01"
        },
        "scores" : {
            "math" : 3.0,
            "science" : 2.0
        }
    }
]
}
```

below is my mongoDB query.

```
    db.students.aggregate([
   {
     $project: {
       mathAve: { $avg: "$math"},
       scienceAve: { $avg: "$science" },
     }
   }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple ways of solving your problem for single person document.

The below query [$divide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/)s  two operands by [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/)ing the `tests` document to sum of its field (`math` and `science`) values followed by [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of `tests` array to calculate the avg.

[Expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#expressions) $ and $$ to reference the fields / aggregation operators / aggregation stages and inner variables respectively.

**Mongo Version >=3.4**

```
db.students.aggregate({
   $project: {
      mathAve: {$divide:[{
          $reduce: {
            input: "$tests.scores.math",
            initialValue: 0,
            in: { $sum: [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
         }
       }, {$size:"$tests"}]},
      scienceAve: {$divide:[{
          $reduce: {
            input: "$tests.scores.science",
            initialValue: 0,
            in: { $sum: [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
         }
       }, {$size:"$tests"}]}
    }
})
```

**Mongo Version = 3.2**

The below query [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)s  the `tests` document followed by [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to calculate the [$avg](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) of each field.

```
db.students.aggregate( 
{$unwind:"$tests"},
{$group: { 
       _id:null,
        mathAve: { $avg: "$tests.scores.math"},
       scienceAve: { $avg: "$tests.scores.science" }
    }
})
```